# Most Pythonic way to find/check items in a list with O(1) complexity?

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, python-3.x, time-complexity

The problem I'm facing is finding/checking items in a list with O(1) complexity. The following has a complexity of O(n):

```
'foo' in list_bar
```

This has a complexity of O(n) because you are using the `in` keyword on a `list`. (Refer to [Python Time Complexity](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity))

However, if you use the `in` keyword on a `set`, it has a complexity of O(1).

The reason why I need to figure out O(1) complexity for a list, and not a set, is largely due to the need to account for duplicate items within the list.  Sets do not allow for duplicates.  A decent example would be :

```
chars_available = ['h', 'e', 'l', 'o', 'o', 'z']
chars_needed = ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']

def foo(chars_available, chars_needed):
    cpy_needed = list(chars_needed)
    for char in cpy_needed:
        if char in chars_available:
            chars_available.remove(char)
            chars_needed.remove(char)
        if not chars_needed: return True  # if chars_needed == []
    return False

foo(chars_available, chars_needed)
```

The example is not the focus here, so please try not to get sidetracked by it.  The focus is still trying to get O(1) complexity for finding items in a list.  How would I accomplish that pythonically?

(As extra credit, if you did want to show a better way of performing that operation in Python, pseudocode, or another language, I'd be happy to read it).

Thank you!

**Edit:**

In response to Ami Tavory's answer, I learned you can't make lists faster than O(n), but the suggestion for `collections.Counter()` helped solve the application I was working on. I'm uploading my faster solution for Stack Overflow, the performance was phenomenal! If I'm not mistaken (correct me if I'm wrong), it should be O(1) since it involves only hashable values and no loop iteration.

```
from collections import Counter
chars_available = ['h', 'e', 'l', 'o', 'o', 'z']
chars_needed = ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']

def foo(chars_available, chars_needed):
    counter_available = Counter(chars_available)
    counter_needed = Counter(chars_needed)
    out = counter_needed - counter_available
    if not list(out.elements()): return True
    else: return False

foo(chars_available, chars_needed)
```

Very fast, very pythonic! Thanks!

Comment: You could keep both the list and a set, there are some data structures that might suit you, but they might make some trade offs such as losing the order of the original list.

Comment: In order to find a item in a list you must employ a search algorithm. Set are basically implemented as Hash maps, and because of that they allow you to have O(1).

Comment: Is this purely of theoretical interest or is there a practial application where you need this?

Comment: @Chris_Rands it is primarily theoretical interest; but there is some application needs in terms of performance, as the processor really bogs down the larger the lists are.  This is especially prevalent in competitive coding/hacking.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general, it's impossible to find elements in a `list` in constant time. You could hypothetically maintain both a `list` and a `set`, but updating operations will take linear time.

You mention that your motivation is

> a list, and not a set, is largely due to the need to account for duplicate items within the list. Sets do not allow for duplicates.

and ask not to focus on the example. If this is your motivation, you might want to use instead of a `set`, a `dict` mapping each element to the number of its occurrences.

You might find [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) useful in particular:

```
In [1]: from collections import Counter

In [2]: Counter(['h', 'e', 'l', 'o', 'o', 'z'])
Out[2]: Counter({'e': 1, 'h': 1, 'l': 1, 'o': 2, 'z': 1})
```

Comment: Well, good to know that about lists. nemanjaps's comment in my question helped clear some things about lists and sets up too.

This is a pretty nice alternative to a list.  While I obviously won't use this for everything, it may be just what I need for large operations without using external libraries.

Comment: I edited my question in response to your answer! It was a great solution, helped me out a lot with a problem I was having, as well as understanding time complexity with lists for future problems! Thanks a lot :)